# How to work out difference in position the rotation of a border creates

Tags: html, css, math, sass

I've spent a fair bit searching today, but couldn't find anything that really solved my particular problem.

I've adapted a SASS mixin we have for creating CSS open arrows for use within projects. Faux  arrows, navigation etc.

My problem is that I can't work out how to work out how much to *shift* the position of the element by when:

a) A rotation occurs

b) When the width of the line/border changes.

I know there must be some simple Math to achieve it, but it's been FAR too long for me to remember!

Example as follows:

```css
p {   
    color: red;
    width: 100px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}
  
p::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0rem;
    height: .125rem;
    width: .875rem;
    background: currentColor;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: .25s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

p::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0rem;
    height: .125rem;
    width: .875rem;
    background: currentColor;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: .25s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(135deg);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Arrow</p>
```

The mixin as this:

```
@mixin arrow($width: 1, $length: 6, $position: 0, $placement: right, $rotate: 0) {

    position: relative;

      &:before,
      &:after {
          content: '';
          display: inline-block;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          @if ($placement==right) {
            right: rem($position);
          } @else {
            left: rem($position);
          }
          height: rem($width);
          width: rem($length);
          background: currentColor;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
          transition: $transition-speed $transition-easeInOutSine;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform: translateZ(0) rotate(#{$rotate}deg);

      }
      &:before {
          transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(#{$rotate + 45}deg);
      }
      &:after {
          transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(#{$rotate + 135}deg);
      }

  .is-active &,
      .is-open & {
          &:before {
              transform: translateX(100%) translateY(-100%) rotate(-#{$rotate + 45}deg);
          }
          &:after {
              transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(#{$rotate + 225}deg);
          }
      }

}
```

Examples as follows:

[image: This arrow uses arrow(2, 14, 0)]

[image: And this uses arrow(2, 7, 0)]

I've explained as best I can, I'm hoping this is enough. Basically I'm trying to work out how to close the gap created, based on the numbers I have!

Thank you in advance!

Please excuse any other issues, it's a WIP.

Comment: It would help if you gave us a working demo.

Comment: yeah, please add a code snippet here (html and compiled css)

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking it may be enough to work out from what I had written. I will add one now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ditch trying to align 2 separate elements and create your arrow with a rotated square.

```css
span{
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

span::after{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
 }
```

```html
<span>Arrow</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would've used this had the output given the required results. You don't have the ability to change the length of the arrow lines. Which is what is required for this project.